# Powershell: Unable to receive data from Receive-Job in powershell script

Tags: powershell-5.1

I have a collection of Jobs running that in this case are checking of a machine is running. I have a bit of code that I'm using to handle the Jobs running and get the data back. My issue is that when I run Receive-Job I get a job object not the result from the job.

Here is the main loop of the handler, many of the variables here are initialized before this loop starts.

```
do {
    # Loop Delay
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds $JobDelay
    Write-Output "Current Job Count = $($(Get-Job).count)"

    # Can I start another Job?
    if (($(Get-Job).count) -lt $maxJobCount) {
        # check if we started all addresses
        if ($scanningPos -lt $addressesToScan.count - 1) {
            # Start next Job
            Write-Output "Starting Job for $($addressesToScan[$scanningPos])"
            $job = Start-Job {tnc -ComputerName $addressesToScan[$scanningPos] -Port $port -InformationLevel Quiet} -Name "$($addressesToScan[$scanningPos])"
            $scanningPos++
        }
    } else { # we are at Max Job count
        # loop over all the jobs to find the completed jobs
        # if completed remove from job list and add to completed addresses
        ForEach ($job in Get-Job) {
            if ($job.State -eq "Completed") {                   # Handle Completed Jobs
                Write-Output $job
                $result = Receive-Job -Job $job
                Write-Output "$($job.Name) completed"
                Write-Output $result
                $completedAddresses.Add($job.Name, $result)
                Remove-Job -Job $job
            } elseif ($job.State -eq "Failed") {                # Handle Failed Jobs
                Write-Output "Found a failed Job: $job"
                Remove-Job $job
            }
        }
    }

    # We finished all the scans
    if ($scanningPos -eq $addressesToScan.Count - 1) {
        $stopcode = $true
    }

    Write-Output "Completed Addresses: $($completedAddresses.Count)"

} until ($stopcode)
```

Also I realize that there are many tools out there that can do this for me, but in the environment I have here I am unable to use them.

I have tried to reformat the line where receive-job is run but to no avail

from a terminal I run

```
start-job { tnc 8.8.8.8 }
```

then after a short wait and Get-Job shows it completed i run

```
$result = receive-job -Id $jobid
write-output $($result.pingsucceeded)
```

I get a response of

```
True
```

but the output from the line in the script is the the job object, not the results from the tnc command

```
Id     Name            PSJobTypeName   State         HasMoreData     Location           Command
--     ----            -------------   -----         -----------     --------           -------
1      8.8.8.8         BackgroundJob   Completed     True            localhost          tnc -C...
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?